# How to convert string to binary string in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a string and I want to convert it to a binary string.

```
let content = request_version.to_string() + &request_length.to_string() + request_json;
```

Answer (score 14):

You probably meant a binary representation of your string in the type *String*.

```
fn main() {
    let name = "Jake".to_string();
    let mut name_in_binary = "".to_string();

    // Call into_bytes() which returns a Vec<u8>, and iterate accordingly
    // I only called clone() because this for loop takes ownership
    for character in name.clone().into_bytes() {
        name_in_binary += &format!("0{:b} ", character);
    }
    println!("\"{}\" in binary is {}", name, name_in_binary);
}
```

And that results:

```
"Jake" in binary is 01001010 01100001 01101011 01100101
```

Answer (score 9):

There's no such thing as a binary string in Rust. There's byte strings, which are a special literal used to create arrays of `u8`; they are indistinguishable from other arrays of `u8`.

When you do manipulation of arrays of `u8`, you want to work with `Vec<u8>`, not arrays. If you want to convert a `String` or `str` to an array of `u8`, you get a slice using `as_bytes`. If you want to get a `Vec<u8>` from a `String`, you can use `into_bytes` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution using Iterator.

```rust
let bits: String = txt.into_bytes()
        .iter()
        .map(|&c| format!("{c:08b}"))
        .collect();
```