# Rust: Convert from a binary string representation to ASCII string

Tags: algorithm, rust, binary

I'm trying to convert a `String` which contains the binary representation of some *ASCII* text, back to the *ASCII* text.

I have the following `&str`:

`let binary: &str = "01010010 01110101 01110011 01110100 01100001 01100011 01100101 01100001 01101110 01110011";`

And I want to convert this `&str` to the *ASCII* version, which is the word: "Rustaceans".

Currently I'm converting this word to binary as follows:

```rust
fn to_binary(s: &str) -> String {
  let mut binary = String::default();
  let ascii: String = s.into();

  for character in ascii.clone().into_bytes() {
    binary += &format!("0{:b} ", character);
  }

  // removes the trailing space at the end
  binary.pop();

  binary
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404844/how-to-convert-string-to-binary-string-in-rust)

I'm looking for the function which will take the output of `to_binary` and returns `"Rustaceans"`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This smells suspiciously like a class assignment.

Comment: "looking for the function which will take the output of to_binary and returns "Rustaceans"." there is no such function in the stdlib, you have to go and write it (and I rather expect that's the entire point of the exercise).

Answer (score 3):

Since all are ASCII texts, you can use [u8::from_str_radix](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u8.html#method.from_str_radix), the demo is below:

```rust
use std::{num::ParseIntError};

pub fn decode_binary(s: &str) -> Result<Vec<u8>, ParseIntError> {
    (0..s.len())
        .step_by(9)
        .map(|i| u8::from_str_radix(&s[i..i + 8], 2))
        .collect()
}

fn main() -> Result<(), ParseIntError> {
    let binary: &str = "01010010 01110101 01110011 01110100 01100001 01100011 01100101 01100001 01101110 01110011";
    println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8(decode_binary(binary)?));
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1fc720993496b6a8040d0a27b54e97b2)

`String::from` is more readable, and in case you want `&str` type, use below as converter:

```rust
std::str::from_utf8(&decode_binary(binary)?)
```

Answer (score 1):

There a simple combination of [`str::split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split), [`u32::from_str_radix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_str_radix) and the (currently) unstable [`char::char_from_u32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.from_u32) that you can use for this:

```rust
#![feature(assoc_char_funcs)]

fn bin_str_to_word(bin_str: &str) -> String {
    bin_str.split(" ")
    .map(|n| u32::from_str_radix(n, 2).unwrap())
    .map(|c| char::from_u32(c).unwrap())
    .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let binary: &str = "01010010 01110101 01110011 01110100 01100001 01100011 01100101 01100001 01101110 01110011";
    let word : String = bin_str_to_word(binary);
    println!("{}", word);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=523bf5935c3f3d6b28fcb0a39ce511aa)